# knockout - globalize template afterRender

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is it possible in knockout js to run a function on every template after it is rendered?

I have some enhancements I want to apply but don't want to track each template individually.

Does knockout dispatch an event perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the afterRender option for the template binding, but its a bit ugly since you will get DOM dependencies in your view model. A better way is to use extenders or custom bindings.

edit: IF you still want to go that route you can override the template binding and inject a afterRender option

edit: To override

http://jsfiddle.net/qJcfX/

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I'll probably try overiding the template binding.